# java object equality when the objects load from db

Tags: java, hibernate, equals

Environment: Java, Hibernate

Lets say i execute two db queries:

pseudocode:

```
Author au1 = execute_query_1
Author au2 = execute_query_2
```

and lets assume that the two queries return the same record from the db.

Is it safe to say that the statement:

```
au1.equals(au2)
```

will return true ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you execute your queries with the same session. Hibernate will simply take it from cache.

Comment: it means that hibernate will use its first-level (session) cache and will not try to fetch again the instance from the db?

Comment: By default yes, but probably its configurable.

Answer (score 0):

it is completely safe if object Author overrides equals() method. If it does not, than it is same as typing au1 == au2, which can return anything, these might have been two different instances. Good thing to do is write an automated test for it